# WCF cannot work well when upload to the server

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf

I have written a WCF to use data from a `Sql server` with an `ADO.NET` entity. It runs well on a local machine. However, when I have deployed on a server, the very same service gives me an error.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information:
> Could not load type 'System.Reflection.IntrospectionExtensions' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely building your WCF service using .Net 4.5 and the server only has 4.0 installed.

Try changing your WCF service to use .Net 4.0 and re-upload to the server.

Comment: I change the 4.0 but the functions can only use with wcf

Comment: It cannot be used with ksoap in android